# iOS TextInput height relative to font size react-native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I'm having trouble with the **TextInput** module for React-Native

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html

On Android it's nice and simple, you create the TextInput give it a  font-size and it sets the height of the TextInput control accordingly.

On the other hand, with iOS unless you provide an explicit height for the TextInput in the style it will be 0.

This would be okay normally, but because I use variable font sizes in my app. I need the TextInput height to match the font-size.

I did try setting the text-input height to the same value as the font-size. That didn't work correctly and I don't think the two are relative.

I have some multiline text inputs and I would like to calculate the height I want for them based on the height for a single line.

pseudo code

```
lineHeight = getHeightForFontSize(15);
multiLineHeight = lineHeight * 4; // 4 lines
```

So in summary. How do I get the height for a TextInput view based on the font-size (known in advance).

Answer (score 1):

You can use **onContentSizeChange** for getting font height on multiline textinput. I'm using this for changing height of textinput after getting too long text. But be sure you are using multiline TextInput. Otherwise, it will not work.

```
<TextInput
  style={{height: this.state.height, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
  onChangeText={::this.onMessageChange}
  value={this.props.message}
  multiline
  onContentSizeChange={({ nativeEvent: { contentSize: { width: txtWidth, height: txtHeight } } }) => {
    if (txtHeight > 40) {
      this.setState({
         height: txtHeight,
      });
    }
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that could be a fallback solution. I want the textInput to be 4 lines before it has any text (except for the placeholder text).

In storyboards for ios-xcode. It would be the equivalent of setting the number of lines to 4. Same for a single line TextInput. The input must be able to size itself base on font size with no text present.

Comment: Actually it's working also on mount time. So it will give you native content size on the beginning and you can set that height to your input. @MarkSilver

Comment: Great I'll give it a go